# How to sync local changes with Office online documents

Tags: ms-office, office365, openxml, onedrive, openxml-sdk

I'm working on a C# project with these requirements:

1. Download an Office (Word, Excel or PowerPoint) document from the cloud
2. Change footers and headers of the document using [Open XML SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx)
3. Upload the document back to the cloud

In case, there is some one else editing the document at the some time, will his changes (or mine) be lost?

How can I sync between changes without loosing none of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [OneDrive API](https://api.onedrive.com) to download and upload the documents, you can use an `If-Match` header on the upload to make sure that you will not overwrite anyone else's changes (See [this page](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/upload_large_files.htm#optional-request-headers) for details).

If you're using either the MS Graph SDK or the OneDrive SDK you can provide the header via the `HeaderOption` object when you invoke the request builder's `Request` method.

In the event that the upload does fail with a `412 Precondition Failed` you'd need to download the file again, make your changes, and attempt another upload.

Comment: That's great. In my case, I have to change only footers and headers of a document, is there a way to upload only this part without uploading the whole document?

Comment: Unfortunately not - especially with office documents. Partial replacement is not yet a feature of the OneDrive API, but even if it were office documents are zip files and so the chances of a simple head/footer change not resulting in a significant file change are pretty low.